# Awk printing characters between fields

Tags: awk

I've tried googling for the answer to my question, and i'm sure the answer is out there, I just don't know what to search. Basically what i'm trying to do is take a line from a file grab the *last 2 fields* (seperated by "`\`") and then print those two fields.

However, I want these fields to be printed out *with 2 backslashes in beween* them. (i'm working with windows path's) Here's my statement

```
$ line = C:\Windows\System32\folder1\folder2\folder3\executable.exe

$ echo $line | awk -F "\\" '{print $(NF-2)$(NF-0)}'
```

I want the output to return `folder3\\executable.exe`

My experience with awk is limited. Thank you in advanced for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the command line:

```
$ echo $line | awk 'BEGIN{FS="\\"; OFS="\\\\"} {print $(NF-1), $NF}'
```

will give you

```
folder3\\executable.exe
```

for your `line`

`FS` sets the field separator for the line(s) processed, `OFS` the output field separators. The double `\\` are necessary to escape the special meaning of the single `\`.

Note that your assignment to `line` should enclose the string in `""` with no spaces before/after the `=`. I.e.,

```
line="C:\Windows\System32\folder1\folder2\folder3\executable.exe"
```

Alternatively, this script (so.awk)

```
BEGIN { FS="\\"
        OFS="\\\\"}
{print $(NF-1), $NF}
```

will give you the same output if invoked as `echo $line | awk -f so.awk data.txt` where `data.txt` contains your one (or possibly more) path(s)

*Update*:

In case you should want to print leading double backslashes: `print "", $(NF-1), $NF` will do the trick by adding an empty string at the start, as mentioned in a helpful comment by @Dennis Williamson

Comment: Awesome!! thanks so much. I asked that last question before you added your full answer. This is great. Thank you

Comment: @JaronBradley: To print the leading double backslash: `print "", $NF, $(NF-1)`

Comment: @Levon: Why did you remove the leading double backslash in the question?

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Good/useful point (and easily done) if needed - thanks (though OP only mentioned printing the last 2 fields with `\\\` between them -- but just in case :)

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Because OP said they wanted to print the last 2 fields with `\\\`  (can't get double quotes to work :-/) between them .. I just made the output consistent with the text (and the acceptance of the OP of my answer)

Comment: I would have asked the OP to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

The variable you want to set is OFS, for Output Field Separator.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `rev` for reverse the string, split your string on the '\' separator and then take the first two string in the array.
In the end, compose the string with the previous separator '\' and reverse again.

The reverse is necessary because you can't always know the numbers of sub-directory between the root and the last one.

Comment: [`tac`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tac) reverses the order of lines (top to bottom). You mean [`rev`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rev) which reverses left to right.

Comment: You are right, thanks for the correction. I edit it immediately